# can a variable be passed in array in java as its size

Tags: java

I am taking a variable from user and wants the array of same size as that of variable. So if I pass that variable in it as its size it shows me an error so is there any wayout for it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class passingtheparcel
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstline;
        String song;
        int n;
        System.out.println("enter the no. of students");
        firstline = obj.nextLine();
        n = Integer.parseInt(firstline);
        System.out.println("enter the lyrics of song");
        song = obj.nextLine();

        int[n] a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println("enter the no. of students");

int[] a = new int[obj.nextInt()];
```

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for initializing an array of length n is :

```
int[] a = new int[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Demo{
    public static void main(String a[]){
        Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstline;       
        int n;
        System.out.println("Enter the no. of students");
        firstline=obj.nextLine();
        n=Integer.parseInt(firstline);
        int arr[]=new int[n];
    }
}
```

Please try this this is working sample.